# Mocha istanbul not covering one file

Tags: node.js, gruntjs, mocha.js, istanbul

I am using grunt mocha istanbul to run my test cases and check for code coverage. When I run the command npm test, all my test cases in every file gets executed. However when it comes to code coverage one of the files is not checked. Interestingly all files in that folder have been tested for code coverage.

I am not able to find any error logs which states where the problem is either. Could someone guide me?